# The picture is not being shown when clicked on addImage button. What is missing in the code?

Tags: android

I am trying to add Image from Gallery to show up in my app. But it is not showing after I select the image from the gallery. It is not showing any error and runs successfully on my device.

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE=1;

public void addImage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if((requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (null !=data)){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.memeImage);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this with uri 
imageView.setImageUri(selectedImage )